# Getting JSON from URL in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, getjson, angularjs-scope

I have a node.js server providing the AngularJS app on port 8000, and a Python server exposing data over HTTP as JSON on port 80.

Loading in my browser `http://localhost:8000/app/List.html` renders a [blank page](http://pastie.org/7912587). Why?

#### Controllers.js

```js
function FooListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('localhost/foo/list').success(function (data) {
        $scope.foo_lists = data;
    });
}

FooListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
```

#### List.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="FooListCtrl">
        <code>{{foo_lists | json}}</code>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### curl -X GET localhost/foo/list -i

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 15 May 2013 18:28:49 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.4
Content-Length: 30
Content-Type: application/json

{"Foo": ["bar", "can", "haz"]}
```

Comment: How do you access the `index.html`. From a webserver or as `file://`? Does you server allow cross orgin requests?

Comment: @TheHippo OP included the URL he's using and mentions he's loading in a browser. The XHR does not include the http:// scheme but should still work.

Did you try using $scope.$apply() inside the success() callback? I thought the $http service handled that but maybe not.

Comment: @jkoreska You're right. But he also mentions the html is coming from port 8000 and the JSOn from port 80, so it looks like it is still a cross orgin issue.

Comment: Oh, so I need to serve the JSON from the same server+port as the static/client-side content? - That's odd. How would I consume third-party APIs then?

Comment: @TheHippo You, sir, are also right! FooStack - by default your browser will only make requests to the origin scheme/host/port - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: The basic concepts are described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
Why not deliver the HTML throught the Python server on port 80?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely, as others have mentioned, a cross-origin issue. It's not only about using the same domain, but also the same port. To bypass this, you can either [use JSONP](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#jsonp), which is a very easy solution designed for this very purpose or use the [Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#crosssiterequestforgeryxsrfprotection), which uses cookie validation and other measures to ensure security while providing get and post functionality (this is not the easiest solution).